# Ansible check if file is encrypted by ansible-vault

Tags: encryption, ansible, ansible-vault

I need to encrypt a file using `ansible-vault`. I would like to perform the encryption only if the file is not already encrypted by ansible vault. I am trying to use this task in my Ansible playbook:

```
- local_action: command
    ansible-vault encrypt path/to/file
  when: <when file is not already encrypted by ansible-vault>
```

Is there a logic to use in the conditional statement that will check if a file is already encrypted by `ansible-vault`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is likely a myriad of ways to do it, all having little to do with Ansible and Ansible Vault itself. Here's one:

```
- local_action: shell
    head -1 {{ file }} | grep -v -q \$ANSIBLE_VAULT && ansible-vault encrypt {{ file }}
```

You'll also need `--vault-password-file` otherwise Ansible will stop processing and wait on prompt.

Comment: Thanks! Yup, I have the vault password file set up as you were saying. In `grep -v -q \$ANSIBLE_VAULT` are you just checking if the file starts with the text `$ANSIBLE_VAULT`?

Comment: Checking if the line in stdin does not have `$ANSIBLE_VAULT` string.

Comment: Oh, yeah, only encrypt if it does not have it. I see it is simpler than I was thinking....I thought ansible-vault had some built-in functionality for this. Thanks!